# What is the difference between $.param & JSON.Stringify

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code:

```
$http({
                url: config.apiUrl + 'mail/Sendmail',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        Body: $scope.Message,
                        Email: $scope.Email,
                        Name: $scope.Name
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
                    }
                })
```

It returns

```
{"Body":"test","Email":"test","Name":"test"}:""
```

This doesn't seem to work because of the :"" at the end, otherwise it looks exactly like my working Postman call.

When I change my data code to:

```
data: $.param({
                        Body: $scope.Message,
                        Email: $scope.Email,
                        Name: $scope.Name
                    }),
```

I get form data under parameters and I no longer see JSON in my network tab, but it works great against:

```
public bool SendEmail(EmailRequest email)
```

Why does JSON.Stringify append `:""` to my call?

Comment: It doesnt: http://jsfiddle.net/ngkjzwm7/

Comment: because your server isn't parsing the json as json. It is instead treating it as if it were params.

Comment: @KevinB did you downvote the question & answer? If so, please explain why.

Comment: @lin the question is poorly researched, the answer started with "Try" rather than stating what is wrong.

Comment: @KevinB IMO no reason for a downvote.

Comment: @lin to each their own.

Comment: Kevin B, are you saying my web api server should be able to parse the :""? Doesn't sound right, but I can handle it if needed.  How come lin's example doesn't have the :"", but mine does? The data set looks pretty similar.  I'm thinking this is an Angular thing if anything.

Comment: @RandomUs1r No, what i'm saying is your webserver is seeing your content type that says the data is in format A, and therefore attempts to parse the data (which happens to instead be in format B) as if it were in format A, giving you the result you are seeing. If you instead told your webserver that it was in format B, and your webserver was capable of parsing data in format B, it would do so.

Comment: So you think it's my CORS header? Maybe, I've never used it before.  I pass {} JSON in Postman with the application/json and it doesn't add the :"", so it's as good a place as any to troubleshoot.  However, is there a definitive source that documents this? Part of me posting my issue on here is I couldn't find anything explaining the :"" on google.  Perhaps my google foo needs work, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like in this [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dwsz0brL/) and use `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`. `JSON.stringify()` works fine, its the content-type which matters.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.output = JSON.stringify({
      Body: 'some',
      Email: 'email@email.com',
      Name: 'name'
    });

    $http({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      method: 'POST',
      data: $scope.output,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
});
```

---

If you still want to send it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-` try this [runnable fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qcxvmo15/). You need to transform your data as an URL encoded string:

```
    $http({
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        Body: 'some',
        Email: 'email@email.com',
        Name: 'name'
      },
      transformRequest: function(obj) {
          var str = [];
          for(var p in obj)
          str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
          return str.join("&");
      },
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
    })
```

Comment: Not a downvoter, but that application/x header is CORS specific.  Tbd why I need CORS in my SOA app, but that's a separate issue.  Unfortunately, it looks like I can only have 1 content type.  As far as manually formatting JSON strings goes, $.params is a lot easier to use at that point.

Comment: This questions is banned =)